# Proving an inequality involving radicals

Tags: inequality

I need some help proving the follwoing inequality:
Knowing that $a \ge 1$, prove that: $$ \frac {1}{\sqrt{a}}\gt 2\sqrt{a+1}-2\sqrt{a}$$
I need to prove this in an algebric fashion. I was thinking about squaring it and playing with it for a bit, but things could get messy...
Any ideas?

Comment: Things *could* get messy, but how will you know without trying? Try it and show the result and we can help you out better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{a}} > \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a+1} + \sqrt{a}} = \sqrt{a+1} - \sqrt{a}$. Thus:

$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}} > 2(\sqrt{a+1} - \sqrt{a}) = 2\sqrt{a+1} - 2\sqrt{a}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Try bringing $2\sqrt{a}$ over to the left side and then squaring both sides.